Boot drive for Windows Server : is a SATA SSD enough?
Just got a used HP Z640 dual Xeon E5-2683v4 from eBay. Planning to install Windows Server and it will mostly be used for hosting a SQL Server database.
So the question is, should I simply install the OS on a ssd sata drive (which came with it), or should I put on a NVME m.2 stick ? I would purchase the Z Turbo Drive g2 adapter card if I go with the 2nd option.
I'm asking because the OS will be sitting there, pretty idle, as I'll have the DB on a separate drive, so I'm not sure I'll see a big boost in performance (aside from boot time) by moving from SATA to NVME.
So not sure if it's worth the trouble of adding a new adapter card, purchasing an NVME stick, tweaking the BIOS, etc.

Do you expect a significant amount of reads/writes? You said "the OS will be sitting there, pretty idle" so is there anything else that would require above-SATA throughput? (...For that matter, in your situation, does the database itself need above-SATA throughput anyway?) I feel like this is something that could be measured; the OS would show you whether the disk is busy with requests.

Just test this. It should be fine, but measure, not guess. Maybe, you have to read a configuration manual and tweak a few things in a database to make sure it wouldn't store anything on the system drive. I presume you've already figured out how to store database file and a transaction log on NVME, but here might be other temporary files, like on-disk sorting of huge result sets, that, if stored on SATA, would affect the database performance.

I don't expect a large amount of read/writes on the boot drive.  I think I'll keep it on Micron SATA and will have the DBs on the NVME stick.
